# Why true -> true vacuum instantons (tunneling) not possible in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, instantons

According to [Tanedo in his text 't Hooft and $\eta$'ail](https://www.classe.cornell.edu/~pt267/files/documents/A_instanton.pdf) (see paragraph 2.6), unlike the case in QM, true->true vacuum tunneling in QFT is prohibited.

They do explain the reason, but I still do not understand it. Particularly why we have a "finite" volume to multiply by in case of false -> true vacuum tunneling, can you please clarify that?

Comment: Please, please ask only one question per post.

Comment: @DanielSank Ok...

Answer (score 1):

False vacuum tunneling --- from higher energy "vacuum" to a lower energy true vacuum ---  only requires the formation of a finite radius bubble. Once the energy gain (proportional to the volume) from creating a region of true vacuum beats the cost of overcoming the potential barrier (proprtional to the surface area of the bubble) it's all downhill in energy as the bubble expands. So the tunneling requires only a finite cost in Action. This cost, however, increases as the energy difference between the true and false vacuum decreases. So tunneling is impossible between degenerate vacuua in a scalar field theory.   See section 3 of the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum.

Comment: Sorry but this is already mentioned in the ref. and I read Wiki article before too. I do not know from where this bubble nucleation comes into the game, we have nothing similar in QM as per my knowledge. All references speaking about it as if something obvious, do you know any reference that explains this bubble origin?

Comment: Yes:  Read the references in the Wikipedia article. For example my ancient paper: M. Stone (1977). "Semiclassical methods for unstable states". Phys. Lett. B. 67 (2): 186–183.